# Enviar objeto Blob/ArrayBuffer por WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, blob

Estou fazendo uma conexão de WebSocket e tentando enviar um Objeto Blob/ArrayBuffer resultante de uma gravação de tela, porem oque chega no servidor no lugar dos bytes é

```
[object ArrayBuffer]
```

Exemplo de codigo :

```
    var arrayBuffer;
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(event) {
        arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
        socket.send("{\"data\":\"" + arrayBuffer + "\"}");
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

Desde já agradeço a quem colaborador.

Answer (score 1):

Depois de um tempo nesse problema resolvi, e venho deixar aqui a resposta pra caso alguém ache essa pergunta posteriormente. 
Resolvi com o seguinte código

```
  socket.send("{\"data\":\"" + _arrayBufferToBase64(byteArray) + "\"}");

  function _arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    return window.btoa( binary );
 }
```

Acho que vale falar que tive problemas com envios muito grandes, então mudei de abordagem de WebSocket pra Socket.io, mas ai tive que mudar meu backend por não ter lib socket.io para a linguagem